# React input type number onChange stops firing after two dashes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Please see [playground](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-gns63).

The code is this:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const App = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState("");
  const handleChange = ({ target }) => {
    setValue(target.value);
    console.log(target.value);
  };
  return <input type="number" value={value} onChange={handleChange} />;
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

It has a weird behaviour. Once you have two dashes in the input, `handleChange` stops firing. I understand that it's not a valid number anymore, but the input has been changed, so `onChange` should be called. Why is this happening?

Comment: Your input is type "number" so your browser will still validate the input, and there is some disagreement over whether or not to accept other characters: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1398528

Answer (score 2):

This by definition of change event. After you enter first -, value of your input is not a number anymore and after that whatever you add, value is still not a number. So it is not changing.
Check change_event MDN docs, it says "Unlike the input event, the change event is not necessarily fired for each alteration to an element's value."
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event

Answer (score 0):

The first - represents a negative number. So it is valid number input. But the second - makes it --, which is an invalid number input. That's why its not firing onChange handler.